# Bootstrap Select large list scrolls the page down (I can't use max-height / Scrollbars)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am using bootstrap select plugin to generate custom dropdowns in one of my projects but I am stuck in a very critical issue. The dropdown list is big and when dropdown is opened the screen moves/scrolls toward bottom a bit so that first few options can't be seen.

Issue can be seen here in this video:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SWQVvfOgO0-iLy0KjIf3sPEANKu8Nkpv/view

And if you want to play around please check here the color filter:
https://www.stylorita.com/new1/outfit-ideas.php

[image: Issue screenshot]

**Important:** I can not use the max-height or add a scrollbar to it for fixing, I must display it without scrollbar. Please anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the solution is for whatever reasons NOT a scrollbar, but you want the first entries of your dropdown list to stay in view, right?

Maybe JS scrollIntoView() may help: If you have the chance to apply a class to your first list entry, you could use scrollIntoView when the list opens (which is normally the case at getting the focus or on click).

You can find a short description of scrollIntoView on this page: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_scrollintoview.asp

Comment: thank you for your response, but I have tried much of these jquery / javascript fixes like disabling scroll, scrolling back but it's not making it user friendly.

Comment: How about hiding an input or a button in the first list item and setting autofocus?

Comment: Not really, what I am thinking to do is to add a disabled option as 'Select a color' to cover up the space it scrolls down. Lol